# Error with serialization when running the program outside the IDE (Java)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I serialize certain objects as a way of saving temporal data. So, to access those objects from the program, I deserialize them, obviously. Now, when I run the program from netbeans, which is the IDE where Im developing it, it works perfectly. But when I execute it from the jar file, it throws the next error:

```
There has been an error when recovering object java.io.ObjectInputStream@4c2cc639:
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3742318830738515599, local class serialVersionUID = 4588530037560142483
```

As you may notice, it says something about the serialVersionUID. So, there are multiple classes involved in this process, I've tried setting the serialVersionUID of all of them, and it has not worked. I have no clue, so, Im gonna leave here the important code involved, and appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is the method where the error originates:

```
    public final static ArrayList<Preset> obtenerListaPresets() {

        final ArrayList<Preset> REGISTROPRESETS = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File p : pCarpeta.listFiles()) {

            try {
                
                REGISTROPRESETS.add((Preset) Serializar.recuperarObjeto(p.getAbsolutePath())); //Arreglar

            } catch (final Exception ex) {

                DialogoInfo.mostrar("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar el preset: " + p.getName() + "\nSi el error persiste, eliminar el archivo:" + p.getAbsolutePath(), 350, 270);
                System.out.println("ocurrio un error en obtenerlistapresets: " + ex);

            }

        }

        return REGISTROPRESETS;
    }
```

The error is thrown specifically in the line

```
REGISTROPRESETS.add((Preset) Serializar.recuperarObjeto(p.getAbsolutePath()));
```

because the method "recuperarObjeto()" returns null

Now, the method "recuperarObjeto()" which is the one in charge of deserializing the object, is this:

```
public static Object recuperarObjeto(String ubicacion_del_objeto) {

    if (!ubicacion_del_objeto.endsWith(".dat")) {

        ubicacion_del_objeto = ubicacion_del_objeto + ".dat";

    }

    if (ubicacion_del_objeto.startsWith("file:/")) {

        ubicacion_del_objeto = ubicacion_del_objeto.replaceFirst("file:/", "");

    }

    if (new File(ubicacion_del_objeto).exists()) {

        ObjectInputStream recuperar = null;

        try {

            recuperar = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(ubicacion_del_objeto));

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            try {
                recuperar.close();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
                Dialogo.crear(Dialogo.INTENTO + "cerrar el flujo del objeto " + recuperar.toString() + " a recuperar:\n" + ex1);
            }

            Dialogo.crear(Dialogo.ERROR + "el objeto a recuperar q se encuentra en la ubicacion:\n" + ubicacion_del_objeto + "\n" + ex);

        }

        try {

            return recuperar.readObject();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Dialogo.crear(Dialogo.INTENTO + "recuperar el objeto " + recuperar.toString() + ":\n" + ex);

        } finally {

            try {
                recuperar.close();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
                Dialogo.crear(Dialogo.INTENTO + "cerrar el flujo del objeto " + recuperar.toString() + " a recuperar:\n" + ex1);
            }

        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

The error is thrown by the method "readObject()" from ObjectInputStream, in the line

```
return recuperar.readObject();
```

Comment: The path to the files is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java serialisation it is really important that to add `transient` declaration on fields which are not required as part of the saved state of your class - as serialisation traverses the network of all non-transient fields of your class.

```
class Prefix implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    transient JComponent panel; // Not saved in serialised state
    String someImportantValue;
}
```

Most likely you have declared your `Prefix` class with too many non-transient object references, one of which has serialised a `JComponent`. If you don't use `transient` on the non-essential fields you may end up writing a lot more classes to the saved state.

While this isn't apparently an issue in same JRE versions, de-serialise across different JRE may not handle incompatible versions of all the definitions.

The load strategy for your app should re-create UI components to match the saved state - and not to serialise the UI components as part of the saved state.

Other helpful [reading](https://www.baeldung.com/java-transient-keyword)